# I am using class components in Reactjs. I want to set the state of child component through a function in Parent Component. How to do it?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So basically, I have a delete button in my parent component and whenever I click on that button, some function should be called that will change or reset a state variable of child component. I am unable to think of a solution here. I basically am a Java developer but now have to handle some frontend stuff as well that involves React. Any help would be appreciated!

Unable to think of an approach here.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn more about the basics of [React](https://react.dev/learn).

Anyway here is an example:

```html
const ChildComponent = (props) => {

const {onButtonClick} = props

  return (
    <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Set to false</button>
  
  )


}

const Parent = () => {
  const [booleanButton,setBooleanButton] = useState(false)


  const onButtonClick = () => setBooleanButton(!booleanButton)

  return (
    <>
      <ChildComponent onButtonClick={onButtonClick}/>
    </>
  )

}
```

If your state management is going to be more complex and you'll need to access the values from a diffrent component, or even a diffrent component tree you should use [React context](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started).

Here's a [Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/g2ewpm)

Answer (score 1):

Like another answer mentioned, you need to "lift" the state up in the parent component, and have that update it. The state can be passed to the child component as a prop.

Here is an example using class components:

```js
import { Component } from 'react';

export class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Store the state in the parent component
    this.state = {
      foo: [1, 2, 3],
    };
  }

  handleDelete() {
    this.setState({ foo: [] });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        // Pass it to the child component as a prop
        <Child foo={this.state.foo} />
        <button onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this)}>Delete</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.foo}</div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can lift the state from the child to the parent component and pass the required parent state as a prop to the child component.

You can read more about this here :
https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html